# change your environment while running your tests cases

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have to change my rails environment while running my tests cases.

```
if Rails.env.production?
  # Do something
else
  # Do something else
end
```

How do i change my rails environment in mid of tests cases.
I am using rails 2.3.16 and ruby 1.9.3

Comment: You shouldn't be even trying to do that. There are simpler ways to achieve what you want (whatever that is).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev simpler ways like?? can you provide some more info.

Comment: Can you provide some more info first? What are you trying to do, ultimately?

Comment: Why are you accessing production & staging environments while running tests?!! Tests run in their own environment. Would be helpful if you review http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: the above code is not in my test case.
This is a valid code and i need to write test case for that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test that code you need to stub that call by doing something like this.

`Rails.stub_chain(:env, :production?).and_return(true)`

That will basically make any call to `Rails.env.production?` return true.

You didn't give much of what framework you're using to run test cases so that works in RSpec with mocks.

That will make whatever call you're doing go in to that block of code so you can write tests against it.

Comment: thanks have to modify your solution a little bit as I am not using RSpec in my app.

Answer (score 1):

To test the above mention code you can change your environment as mentioned by @Leo if you ar using RSpec. 
If you are using Rails built in framework to write the test cases then  You can do this.

```
Rails.env.stubs(:production?).returns(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Rails.env.stubs(:production?).returns(true)
```

if you are using rails built-in testing framework for writing your test cases.

Answer (score 0):

**This question is better articulated like this (see below). I tried submitting these as edits to the original question but some "smart" reviewers decided to reject my edits. Interestingly, those who rejected my edits seem to have zero experience with ruby/rails**

I have to write test cases for a piece of application code which is dependent on rails environment. The code reads like this:

```
if Rails.env.production?
   # Do something
else
   # Do something else
end
```

How do i simulate rails environment in my test cases so that I can test both the `if` part and `else` part of the logic?

I am using rails 2.3.16 and ruby 1.9.3